# ember.js how to create a base component

Tags: ember.js

I have three ember components in my app. all of them have `acceptDecline` function which is doing almost the same thing and also has a property name `isContentHidden` for hiding and showing content. I think its duplicate code. My goal is to create a base component. How do I do it in ember.js. I read this article: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/16/subclass-emberjs-components/ but they don't have any code example. any idea how can I do it. these are my all three component:

```
App.PendingHotelRequestsComponent= Ember.Component.extend({
    isContentHidden: false,
    actions:{
        acceptDecline: function(isStatusAccept){
            this.sendAction('accept', 'hotelrequest', {
                id: this.get('hotelRequest.pk'),
                validated_timestamp: isStatusAccept ? moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD H-m-ss") : '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
            });
            this.set('isContentHidden', true);
        }
    }
});
App.PendingAcceptedOffersComponent= Ember.Component.extend({
    isContentHidden: false,
    actions:{
        accept: function(){
            this.sendAction('accept', 'inquiry', {
                id: this.get('inquiry.id'),
                validated_timestamp: moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD H-m-ss")
            });
            this.set('isContentHidden', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any way I can create a base component that will have these functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use a mixin, or extend from a base component to accomplish easy reusability.

#### Mixin

```
App.FooMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
   isContentHidden: false
});

App.PendingHotelRequestsComponent= Ember.Component.extend(App.FooMixin, {
    actions:{
        acceptDecline: function(isStatusAccept){
            this.sendAction('accept', 'hotelrequest', {
                id: this.get('hotelRequest.pk'),
                validated_timestamp: isStatusAccept ? moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD H-m-ss") : '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
            });
            this.set('isContentHidden', true);
        }
    }
});
```

- *Quick note about mixins, you'll use `create` instead of extend when defining them.*

#### Base Component

```
App.BaseComponent = Em.Component.extend({
   isContentHidden: false
});

App.PendingAcceptedOffersComponent= App.BaseComponent.extend({
    actions:{
        accept: function(){
            this.sendAction('accept', 'inquiry', {
                id: this.get('inquiry.id'),
                validated_timestamp: moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD H-m-ss")
            });
            this.set('isContentHidden', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: is there any benefit using Mixin or Base Class ?